# Function pointer to variadic lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-functions

Why does the compiler deny conversion of variadic lamda to function pointer?
The conversion works perfectly fine without the variadic args.

```
    auto lambda = [] (void *, const char *) {};
    auto variadicLambda = [] (void *, const char *, auto ...) {};

    auto ptrLambda = +[] (void *, const char *) {};
    auto ptrVariadicLambda = +[] (void *, const char *, auto ...) {};
```

Tried with gcc 12.2 and clang 15.0.0.

```
<source>:7:30: error: invalid argument type '(lambda at <source>:7:31)' to unary expression
    auto ptrVariadicLambda = +[] (void *, const char *, auto ...) {};
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

https://godbolt.org/z/G6cnK6oxP

Comment: What function pointer type would it give?

Comment: Using `auto` creates a [generic lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), which is a templated functor and templates are not objects.

Comment: because `(void *, const char *, int)` and `(void *, const char *, float)` are different function and cannot squeeze into same pointer. (and what's the pointer type is another problem)

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the compiler deny conversion of variadic lamda to function pointer?

Because there is no overloaded `operator+` that takes a [generic lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) as its argument. This is because the use of `auto` in the parameter of the lambda makes it a *generic lambda* but since there is no `operator+` for a generic lambda we get the mentioned error. This is exactly what the [error](https://godbolt.org/z/Mc761T41W) says:

```
no match for 'operator+' (operand type is '<lambda(void*, const char*, auto:17 ...)>')
   12 | auto ptrVariadicLambda = +[] (void *, const char *, auto ...) {};
```